# How can I use Animated.Value as a scale?

Tags: react-native

If I create:

`const fontScale = new Animated.Value(1);`

And then on some change, I update it:

```
Animated.timing(fontScale, {
  duration: keyboardDuration,
  toValue: keyboardHeight > 0 ? 0.75 : 1
}).start();
```

How can I then use that as a multiplier for something like `fontSize`?

For example, I've got a header here which I want to make smaller when the `fontScale` changes:

```
<Animated.Text
  style={[
  typography.heading1,
  typography.largeText,
  typography.bolded,
  { fontSize: fontScale }
  ]}
>
  Choose a name
</Animated.Text>
```

I get a type error if I try to multiply:

```
<Animated.Text
  style={[
  typography.heading1,
  typography.largeText,
  typography.bolded,
  { fontSize: fontScale * SOME_NUMBER }
  ]}
>
  Choose a name
</Animated.Text>
```

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated.html#multiply wow

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  You just use https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated.html#multiply

For example:

`{ fontSize: Animated.multiply(fontScale, 48) }`